# Why would mounting / unmounting an XFS filesystem make it bootable again?

Tags: amazon-ec2, xfs

I’ve got some EC2 instances running Amazon Linux 2 and 2023 which use XFS as their root volume. Occasionally, after several reboots, the instance refuses to boot and gives a kernel panic, because it cant find the volume specified by the `root=<some-uuid>` kernel parameter:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=<some-uuid>" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
```

Now this is where it gets weird. If I take the root volume from one of these "broken" instances, attach it to an intermediate EC2 instance, and (this is important) mount/unmount the filesystem, I can reattach it to the formerly broken EC2 instance and everything boots just fine.

Because its XFS, I assumed that there was some corruption happening. Instead of mounting it, I tried running xfs_repair. This tool refuses in every instance to repair the volume because there are log entries:

```
ALERT: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which is being
ignored because the -n option was used.  Expect spurious inconsistencies
which may be resolved by first mounting the filesystem to replay the log.
```

Dropping the log with `-L` does not make the volume bootable again.

I assume this means that the XFS log is corrupting the UUID identifier. Why would replaying the log via mount fix it, and is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: `(this is important) mount/unmount the filesystem` so can you mount with its UUID (instead of the dev node) when you have it attached to another instance? And have you indeed confirmed that just "detach attach detach attach" doesn't help? (Somehow I still feel like it's either some kind of race or some hypervisor side problem.)

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the mount is required. Attaching and Detaching from another instance does not solve the problem. Attaching, and mounting does.

The UUID shown by `lsblk` matches what it should be in the `root=` kernel command line, too.

Answer (score 0):

**XFS Log Replay**: When you mount an XFS filesystem, it replays the log to bring the filesystem to a consistent state. This process helps to ensure data integrity. In your case, mounting and unmounting the filesystem on an intermediate EC2 instance triggers the log replay and may fix inconsistencies in the filesystem metadata.

**Prevention**
Contact AWS  Support

Another possible solution is to generate a new UUID for the affected XFS partition using the xfs_admin command. For example:

`sudo xfs_admin -U generate /dev/nvme4n1p2`

This will clear the log and set a new UUID for the device. However, this may also cause some data loss or corruption, so it is recommended to backup your data before doing this.